# How to check if all elements of a list are contained in other one

Tags: python, pandas

I've two list and need to check if all elements of list_1 are contained in list_2 id not, save those elements in a new list.

SO I've this:

```
list_1 = ['item','item','item']
list_2 = ['item_2','item_2','item_2']
list_3 = []

for i in range(len(list_1)):
    flag = True
    aux = list_1[i]
    for j in range(len(list_2)):
        if aux == list_2[j]:
            flag == False
            break
    if flag:
        list_3.append(aux)
```

But this is very slow, there is a way to improve the speed?

maybe some built pandas function?

Edit.

I don't need pandas to this, but the list are infact columns two Data Frames, I just write it with list because it's a more general case.

Comment: If you're trying to compare lists, then why don't you just write `list_1==list_2`, if you want the matching elements, then try `set(list_1)&set(list_2)`

Comment: Are you question about `list` or something like `pd.Series` of `pd.DataFrame`?

Comment: Why do you need Pandas for this?

Comment: The best way is [_probably without Pandas_] to do this: `len(set(list1).intersection(list2)) > 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC I think you could use `isin` and `all` methods of `pd.Series`:

```
import pandas as pd
l1, l2 = map(pd.Series, [list_1, list_2])

In [3]: l1      
Out[3]:         
0    item       
1    item       
2    item       
dtype: object   

In [4]: l2      
Out[4]:         
0    item_2     
1    item_2     
2    item_2     
dtype: object   

In [5]: l1.isin(l2)
Out[5]:
0    False
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool

In [6]: l1.isin(l2).all()
Out[6]: False
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be interested in the union and difference of [sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29).

You could check for these, like this:

```
a = set([1, 5, 6, 0])
b = set([0, 8, 2, 3, -5])
a.difference(b)   # returns: {1, 5, 6}
a.intersection(b) # returns {0}
b.difference(a)   # returns: {-5, 2, 3, 8}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the elements in `list_1` that are not in `list_2` and save them in an other list, in this case, `list_3`, you can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
>>> list_3 = [i for i in list_1 if i not in list_2]
```

Comment: Great, it will be faster or is just more succinct?

Answer (score 1):

I find numba to be fun for loops, it really brings up the speed with minimum effort:

```
from numba import jit
@jit
def jitstack():
    list_1 = ['item','item','item']
    list_2 = ['item_2','item_2','item_2']
    list_3 = []
    for i in range(len(list_1)):
        flag = True
        aux = list_1[i]
        for j in range(len(list_2)):
            if aux == list_2[j]:
                flag == False
                break
        if flag:
            list_3.append(aux)
```

Timed with timeit in iPython notebook: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0KNIF4xMP3UNW93LWlmWUFqbnc/view?usp=sharing

Original: 3.72 µs per loop

Numba: 22.4 ns per loop

and also the list_3 = [i for i in list_1 if i not in list_2]: 1.22 µs per loop

Comment: You didn't actually time this on that small dataset did you? I'm not saying numba isn't a good tool (it definitely is), but just that your timings are rather unrepresentative of actual performance. Numba's JIT might even precompile the entire code to just `pass` as nothing is being returned from those functions.

Comment: What is the size of your lists?

Comment: As you can see from my link the dataset is small. I've tested with a larger data set, returning list_3: Original code: 7.58s best loop, Numba: 12.2 ms per loop (slowest 14.5s longer (caching), 3rd option 1.71s per loop. There may be ways to improve the way timing is performed, however it would be interesting to see the improvement on the actual case.